# How to unset global variables.

Tags: php, jquery, session-variables, unset

I have an `id` of a project and an `id` of a client that are sessions in php that are passed in JSON format. These are stored in global variables `id_p` and `id_c` so I can do multiple inserts and updates selects etc. with those ids.

When the user selects another project or changes the page, I need to unset these variables.

- Can I pass a `null` value from `php` to the global vars to reset them?
- Is there a better way to do what I want?
- How could I store the `php` values on `php` only if the file is required? The files where the queries take place are on separate files.

Comment: Is this a PHP question or a Javascript question? I can't tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would setting them to null or undefined accomplish what you're looking for?

```
id_p = null;
id_c = null;
```

Comment: Ah, I was about to rebuke you for using `delete` on variables. ;) I'm pretty sure you can use `delete` *if* the global was originally created with `window.id_p`, and *if* you use `delete` on the `window` object property. I think `null` is a better option though.

Comment: yes, thanks so lets say that my unsetsession.php parses a json that has id_p and id_c = null and jquery parses the data and changues the variables to tha value obtained is that allright?

Answer (score 4):

To really unset them, use

```
unset ( $GLOBALS['id_p'] );
```

This also works in functions.

Source: http://toscho.de/2012/php-unset-unterschied-global-globals/

Comment: And the source is down. Good it is here now.